# Nested loop openmp

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, numerical-methods

I am trying to transform my code to parallel, I have many functions and my arrays are dynamic. The more computational intensive part is the loop that i am showing int the code that I am adding here.
The code work without a problem if I only run it with one thread, but as long as I am using more, the code crashes. 
I have watched the intel tutorial on youtube and search the answer in the forum here, but I still don't grasp the concept correctly, could you point me out what I am doing wrong?
What I want to do is that every thread runs the code for each NodeNumber. (The first for), Each NodeNumber has its own set of RelatedElemNum that depend of the index of i. Density and VibrationEnergy are global variables that also appear in the Reaction Function. 
Am I missing something?
Thanks!

```
    #pragma omp parallel
            {
 #pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic) private (Density,VibrationEnergy, DQ, m, n, i, j, k, Y, X)

                for(i=0;i<NodeNumber;i++)
                {   
                    Y=0;
                    for(j=0;j<RelatedElemNum[i];j++) 
                    {
                        m=LargeElem[i][j].ElemID;
                        n=LargeElem[i][j].Position;
                        Y=Y+SmallElem[m][n].area;
                    }
                    for(k=0;k<Neq;k++)
                    {
                        X=0;
                        for(j=0;j<RelatedElemNum[i];j++)
                        {
                            m=LargeElem[i][j].ElemID;
                            n=LargeElem[i][j].Position;
                            IndexL=(n-1+element[m].ElemType)%element[m].ElemType;
                            uA=U2[m][k]+Ux2[m][k]*(SmallElem[m][n].Centroid.x-node1[m].x)+Uy2[m][k]*(SmallElem[m][n].Centroid.y-node1[m].y);
                            deltax=element[m].dHx[n];
                            deltay=element[m].dHy[n];
                            fAL=deltay*FLUX_F(U2[m],Ux2[m],Uy2[m],Ut[m],-deltax/2,-deltay/2,dt/4,k);
                            gAL=deltax*FLUX_G(U2[m],Ux2[m],Uy2[m],Ut[m],-deltax/2,-deltay/2,dt/4,k);
                            deltax=-element[m].dHx[IndexL];
                            deltay=-element[m].dHy[IndexL];
                            fAR=deltay*FLUX_F(U2[m],Ux2[m],Uy2[m],Ut[m],deltax/2,deltay/2,dt/4,k);
                            gAR=deltax*FLUX_G(U2[m],Ux2[m],Uy2[m],Ut[m],deltax/2,deltay/2,dt/4,k);

                            if(is_symm==1)
                            {
                                deltax=SmallElem[m][n].Centroid.x-node1[m].x;
                                deltay=SmallElem[m][n].Centroid.y-node1[m].y;
                                sA=SourceTerm(U2[m],Ux2[m],Uy2[m],Ut[m],node1[m].y,deltax,deltay,dt/4,k);

                                X=X+uA*SmallElem[m][n].area+(gAL-fAL+gAR-fAR)*dt/2+sA*SmallElem[m][n].area*dt/2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                X=X+uA*SmallElem[m][n].area+(gAL-fAL+gAR-fAR)*dt/2;
                            }
                        }
                        U1[i][k]=X/Y;
                    }
                    Density=sum(U1[i]);
                    for(k=0; k<Ns; k++)
                    {
                        mass[k]=U1[i][k]/Density;
                    }
                    VibrationEnergy=U1[i][Ns+3];
                    if(VibrationEnergy>0)Tv1[i]=Newton_Tv(Tv1[i]);
                    Reactor(U1[i],DQ,Tv1[i],dt/2);
                    for(k=0; k<Neq; k++)
                    {
                        U1[i][k]=U1[i][k]+DQ[k];
                    }
                    Density=sum(U1[i]);
                    for(k=0; k<Ns; k++)
                    {
                        mass[k]=U1[i][k]/Density;
                    }
                    VibrationEnergy=U1[i][Ns+3];
                    if(VibrationEnergy>0)Tv1[i]=Newton_Tv(Tv1[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Making sub-functions would make the code more readable (as `const int Y = sum_areas(RelatedElemNum[i], LargeElem[i], SmallElem);`) and may help to outpost problem.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. I will try that, but regarding OpenMP, am I missing something?

Comment: You have two consecutive `#pragma omp parallel`. Eliminating the first should help.


If it still doesn't work, try using a memory checker (s.a. valgrind) on a one-thread run just to make sure you're not reading/writing out-of-bounds.


On the "missing something" matter, it's difficult to say: your code is quite complex and some things are not clear (`FLUX_F`, `FLUX_G`, `uA`...). Hence my recomendations